# Array append not working on Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, asynchronous, append

I have this function, but when I run:

```
theRecipes.append(theRecipe);
```

...the size of the array 'theRecipes' is exactly the same. I share you the code so you can overview what I'm trying to do on Swift Language.

```
func retrieveAll() -> [Recipe] {
    var query = PFQuery(className: RECIPE_PARSE_CLASSNAME);
    var theRecipes: [Recipe] = [Recipe]();

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) recipes.");

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let recipes = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for recipe in recipes {
                    let theRecipe: Recipe = Recipe();
                    theRecipe.name = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_NAME_NAME] as String;
                    theRecipe.about = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_ABOUT_NAME] as String;
                    theRecipe.cover = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_COVER_NAME] as String;
                    theRecipe.preview = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_PREVIEW_NAME] as String;

                    println(theRecipe.name);
                    theRecipes.append(theRecipe);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)");
            Bugsnag.notify(nil, withData: ["data": error.description]);
        }
    };

    return theRecipes;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is collect every PFObject to translate it to my own Model class and for managing it that way while in memory. So I translate it and append it to the array to deliver it fulfilled with recipes.

I want to make clear that I already checked that I'm successfully retrieving every object from Parse and they're not null.

Comment: You can't return the array like this from a method that uses an asynchronous method to fetch the data. The return statement will run immediately, before the block in findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is executed.

Comment: You're completely right. I'll fix it right now. But even so, is it normal that when I'm debugging a line after the append the array has still 0 elements?

Comment: Did you do that in the debugger or with a log? If you log theRecipes in the line right after you append it, it should show the correct number of elements.

Comment: How come Parse "`fetchInBackground`" questions are becoming as prevalent as Java string comparison with `==` questions?

Comment: @rdelmar What would be a solution instead?  I'm having the same issue where I need to return an array from an asynchronous method.

Comment: @bakalolo do as I did in my answer below. That works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
func retrieveAll(returner: (Array<Recipe>) -> Void) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: RECIPE_PARSE_CLASSNAME);
    var theRecipes: Array<Recipe> = Array<Recipe>();

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) recipes.");

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let recipes = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for recipe in recipes {
                    let theRecipe: Recipe = Recipe();
                    theRecipe.name = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_NAME_NAME] as String;
                    theRecipe.about = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_ABOUT_NAME] as String;
                    theRecipe.cover = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_COVER_NAME] as String;
                    theRecipe.preview = recipe[RECIPE_PARSE_PREVIEW_NAME] as String;

                    println(theRecipe.name);
                    theRecipes.append(theRecipe);
                }

                returner(theRecipes);
            } else {
                println();
                returner(Array<Recipe>());
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)");
            Bugsnag.notify(nil, withData: ["data": error.description]);
            returner(Array<Recipe>());
        }
    };
}
```

Using a returner method to deliver my mapped recipes asynchronously.